# TCP Time-Sequence Graph Ipython Notebook

Tags: python, tcp, matplotlib

I'm having network traffic data in this location "C:\Users\ASHWIN\Desktop\Test3_pcap.csv". In that file contain frame.number, frame.time, eth.src, eth.dst, ip.src, ip.dst, ip.proto, tcp.stream, tcp.seq, tcp.ack, tcp.window_size and tcp.len which divided in column.

Besides i already declared some importing files in my Ipython notebook which is in below:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import sys
%matplotlib inline
```

I wanted to do plotting graph for TCP-time sequence graph by using my csv file but its turns alot of error. The sample code i did and get error was as below;

```
fields=["tcp.stream", "ip.src", "ip.dst", "tcp.seq", "tcp.ack", "tcp.window_size", "tcp.len"]
   ts=read_csv("C:\Users\ASHWIN\Desktop\Test3_pcap.csv", fields, timeseries=True, strict=True)
   ts

stream=ts[ts["tcp.stream"] == 10]

print stream.to_string()

stream["type"] = stream.apply(lambda x: "client" if x["ip.src"] == stream.irow(0)["ip.src"] else "server", axis=1)

print stream.to_string()

client_stream=stream[stream.type == "client"]
client_stream["tcp.seq"].plot(style="r-o")
```

When I run all this 8 code through my Ipython notebook it show alot of error. Can anyone solve my problem using this network traffic csv file. I wanted to create a TCP-time sequence graph for this network traffic data in csv format. I'm hoping alot is anyone can solve my problem in this ipython notebook.Thank you.

---

My code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import sys
%matplotlib inline

Location = r'C:\Users\ASHWIN\Desktop\tempo\New folderTest3_pcap.csv'
fields=["tcp.stream", "ip.src", "ip.dst", "tcp.seq", "tcp.ack", "tcp.window_size", "tcp.len"]
ts=read_csv(Location, fields, timeseries=True, strict=True)
ts
```

And this is the error I get:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ae8455b41c8b> in <module>()
      1 Location = r'C:\Users\ASHWIN\Desktop\tempo\New folderTest3_pcap.csv'
      2 fields=["tcp.stream", "ip.src", "ip.dst", "tcp.seq", "tcp.ack", "tcp.window_size", "tcp.len"]
----> 3 ts=read_csv(Location, fields, timeseries=True, strict=True)
      4 ts
TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeseries'
```

Comment: Can you post the errors you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

timeseries, as well as strict, are not valid arguments of read_csv()

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Hi Dan, the author complained of errors.  I asked them to be posted (see first comment), the author did and I pointed out why the posted error was occurring.